# Displaying an image from an InputStream

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-imageview

I am able to send strings from my Android mobile phone to my computer, and vice versa. However, I want to send an image from my computer and display it to the mobile phone. In my case, the computer is the server and the mobile phone is the client.

This is part of my code on the server side:

```
socket = serverSocket.accept();
dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
captureScreen("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\capture.png");

File f = new File("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\capture.png");
byte [] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
dataOutputStream.flush();
```

Note that `captureScreen()` is a method that successfully takes a screenshot of the server and save it as a .PNG image in the above path.

Now, on the client side which is the Android mobile phone, if I have an `ImageView` control, how to read the image sent from the computer as an `InputStream` and display it on the `ImageView`?

Furthermore, did I write successfully the image to the `dataOutputStream`? I would be glad if any one helps me !

Answer (score 5):

You can call the `setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)` of your ImageView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

How you get the image data to your client: it depends on the solution you have chosen, but technically you can use the same libraries that you would use for pure Java.

You can use `android.graphics.BitmapFactory` to create the `Bitmap` from your stream.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
```

Comment: Can you show me please some code for how to create the Bitmap from the inputStream ?

Comment: Thanks but decodeStream(inputStream) did not work, I think it is returning null

Comment: You can try different versions, there is a dozen of them there. `null` as a return value means that the input was wrong. I recommend to try it with a local `png` file (e.g. the launcher icon), it should work with that.

Comment: I have manually put an image on my sdcard and tried:
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageName);
img.setImageBitmap(bMap);

And yes you are right it works !

can you provide me please with the code of how yo dynamically creates an image on the sdcard ?

Comment: I think the problem is either (1) with the image format (`jpg` vs `png`), or (2) with the network transport. You can try the same with a jpg image (to check (1)). If it works, try to load the whole image into a `byte[]`, then call `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`

Comment: Also, you can try to open a `FileInputStream` for your `png` file, then feed it to `BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)`.

Answer (score 1):

what is this ?

```
    byte [] buffer = new byte[(int)f.length()];
    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
```

You just declared size of a buffer byte array , but it`s empty!
You should to convert your file to byte and than transfer it to OutputStream , smth like this:

```
    byte[] buffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\capture.png");
```

(code for c#)
And than you will send it like you did:

```
     dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,buffer.length);
     dataOutputStream.flush();
```

try this for file receiving :

```
    public void fileReceived(InputStream is)
throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-1");


if (is!= null) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/chats/gas1.jpg/");
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        byte[] aByte = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;

        while ((bytesRead = is.read(aByte)) != -1) {
            bos.write(aByte, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        bos.flush();
        bos.close();
        Log.i("IMSERVICE", "FILERECCC-2");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // Do exception handling
    }
}
}
}
```

So you`ll got new file in your sd-card on Android.

Comment: can u provie me please with the java code of this conversion?

Comment: Almost the same , @WassiMZgheiB:

        `Path path = Paths.get("path/to/file");
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);`

Comment: @Overrided thanks, I wrote these bytes to the outputStream, but how can I read them on the client side as an inputStream ?

Comment: @WassiMZgheiB i added code to my answer , hope it`ll help you.

Comment: thanks again but it did not work nothing is saved on my sdcard, I got the following error in logcat:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)